# How can I determine the parameters of a beta distribution given a histogram?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a histogram, and I want to estimate the parameters of the underlying distribution.  Here is the data I've taken from the graph:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Interval} & \text{Count}\\
\hline
0-.70 & 0\\
.70-.75 & 1\\
.75-.80 & 21\\
.80-.85 & 36\\
.85-.90 & 59\\
.90-.95 & 69\\
.95-1 & 4\\
\end{array}
$$

So far, I've estimated $\alpha = 33.15$ and $\beta=4.78$. I rounded each point to the center of the range (so $36$ points at $.825$, $59$ at $.875$, etc.).  From this, I found the mean and variance, and solved for the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Is this the best way to do it?

This question is making the *assumption* that the data follows a beta distribution.

Comment: Have you plotted the theoretical density against the histogram?

Answer (score 1):

This is a maximum likelihood kind of question. You have binned your data already, so you can calculate the expected probability of each bin, given $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$$p_i=I_{b_i}(\alpha,\beta)-I_{a_i}(\alpha,\beta),$$

where $I_x(\alpha,\beta)$ is the [regularized incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), and the $i$-th bin is $[a_i,b_i]$. Now we have a multinomial distribution in the bins, with these being the probabilities for each bin, so the likelihood of your result is $L={N\choose n_1,\dots,n_k}p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$. Maximize with respect to $\alpha,\beta$! The multinomial coefficient doesn't depend on $\alpha,\beta$, so you can leave it out, and the log-likelihood is easier for computation:

$$\ell=\sum_in_i\log p_i=\sum_in_i\log(I_{b_i}(\alpha,\beta)-I_{a_i}(\alpha,\beta))$$

According to Mathematica, using your data, the best value is $\ell=-272.57$ at $\alpha=36.39$ and $\beta=5.247$.